# Continuously running script on Parse (server)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am making some sort of lottery app that draws a winner every 48 hours which I made with Parse. Only the problem is that the code to check if the 48 hours have run out cant be on a phone because there is no permanent connection with Parse. Is there a way to have a script continuously running on Parse or on the Parse open source Server with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a Cloud Job. But Cloud Job is not yet available in Parse Server.

The other option is to create a Cloud Function and use an external tool to call this cloud function every hour, for example, and check if 48h has completed.

Another option is to create an interval. Something like it:

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Do what you have to do.
}, 3600000); // Will run every 1h.
```